# Add a row and sort the sheet (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script to sort students into intervention groups, and I want the resulting sheets to be sorted alphabetically.  I also need to add checkboxes to the new row I'm adding.  My code works, but it seems dreadfully inefficient since I add the new row with the checkboxes, grab the new data range, sort it, and then rewrite it to the spreadsheet.  Any help at cleaning it up would be appreciated.

```
function filterToGroup(sheet, student, value) {
  var oldDataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var oldDataValues = oldDataRange.getValues();

  if (value === true) {
    // Add new row to spreadsheet based on filter requirements
    sheet.appendRow([student]);
    // Insert checkboxes after the name to complete the row
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2, 1, oldDataValues[0].length).insertCheckboxes();
    // Get the sheet values with the new row
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, oldDataValues[0].length);
    var newValues = newRange.getValues();
    // Sort them
    var sortedNewValues = newValues.sort(function(a,b) {return a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1});
    // Write the newly sorted values back to the sheet
    newRange.setValues(sortedNewValues);
  } else {
    for (i = 1; i < oldDataValues.length; i++) {
      if (student == oldDataValues[i][0]) {
        sheet.deleteRows(i+1, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

When a teacher clicks on a checkbox under "Phonics", I want the student added to the "Phonics" sheet with checkboxes:
[image: Roster]

[image]

The function that launches the filterToGroup function is

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  var editedColumn = e.range.getA1Notation().charAt(0);
  var editedValue = e.range.getValue();
  var student = rosterValues[e.range.getRow() -1][0];
  if (editedSheet == "Roster") {
    if (editedColumn == "E") filterToGroup(phonicsSheet, student, editedValue);
    if (editedColumn == "G") filterToGroup(phonologicalAwarenessSheet, student, editedValue);
    if (editedColumn == "H") filterToGroup(letterNamesAndSoundsSheet, student, editedValue);
  }
}
```

I think I have it figured out.  It's still not super fast, but it's under a second and doesn't write to the sheet twice.  Once I figured out that I could insert checkboxes after the fact, it really helped.  Here is the new code:

```
function filterToGroup(sheet, student, value) {
  var oldDataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var oldDataValues = oldDataRange.getValues();

  if (value === true) {
    // Check if the student is the first to be added;
    // If so, just append row
    if (oldDataValues.length === 1) {
      phonicsSheet.appendRow([student]);
      // Run the new addCheckboxes function to add checkboxes to row
      addCheckboxes(phonicsSheet, 1, oldDataValues[0].length -1);
    } else {
      // If data has already been added, remove header row
      oldDataValues.shift();
      // Create a new array with the student data and false values
      var newStudent = Array.apply(null, Array(oldDataValues[0].length -1).map(_ => false));
      newStudent.unshift(student);
      // Add the new student to the data and sort
      oldDataValues.push(newStudent);
      var newDataValues = oldDataValues.sort();
      // Write the sorted object to the sheet
      sheet.getRange(2, 1, newDataValues.length, newDataValues[0].length).setValues(newDataValues);
      // Add checkboxes to the sheet (existing true values will still be recognized)
      addCheckboxes(sheet, newDataValues.length, newDataValues[0].length -1);
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 1; i < oldDataValues.length; i++) {
      if (student == oldDataValues[i][0]) {
        sheet.deleteRows(i+1, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function addCheckboxes(sheet, numRows, numCols) {
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, numRows, numCols).insertCheckboxes();
}
```

Comment: I assume you are calling filterToGroup in a loop. If you do, it will surely be very inefficient. What I'd advice is to read all values, add the row(s), make the changes and write everything back to the sheet. Eventually you will have one read and one write operation.
To add checkboxes in that way you will need to reach out to the Sheet service/API and prepare a batch before calling https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#SetDataValidationRequest

Comment: It's not part of a loop.  It triggers when a checkbox is clicked.  If the box is true, it sends the student to the new sheet and sorts it alphabetically.  If it's false, it deletes the row for the student.  It's the checkboxes that are throwing me off.  I know how to do this with just data, but setting the checkboxes is difficult.

Comment: I added additional info to the original post.

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet as well to better grasp your concern.

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g54IH2IGC28Tz_JCJJx394n1NgcNP1l8DA4Q2SXQmRQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work well but if you want to remove some line(s) of code, you can remove the sorting line and directly sort when performing `getValues()`. Your new code should look like this:

```
function filterToGroup(sheet, student, value) {
  var oldDataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var oldDataValues = oldDataRange.getValues();

  if (value === true) {
    // Add new row to spreadsheet based on filter requirements
    sheet.appendRow([student]);
    // Insert checkboxes after the name to complete the row
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2, 1, oldDataValues[0].length).insertCheckboxes();
    // Get the sheet values with the new row
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, oldDataValues[0].length);
    var newValues = newRange.getValues().sort();
    // Write the newly sorted values back to the sheet
    newRange.setValues(newValues);
  } else {
    for (i = 1; i < oldDataValues.length; i++) {
      if (student == oldDataValues[i][0]) {
        sheet.deleteRows(i+1, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
```

This basically removes 1 line in your code but should still function the same way as before.

Comment: That still writes to the sheet twice, which is what I was trying to avoid.  I think I figured it out though.  I'll post my new code.  Thanks!

Comment: I see. That issue wasn't in the original post though. Nevertheless, good to know that you've found the solution. Happy Coding!

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear in the original.  Thank you for your help regardless.

Comment: You did clean up my code, however, and I used those suggestions in my solution.